# Gstreamer taginject pipeline doesnt work

Tags: gstreamer

im trying to construct a pipeline that will read any file (mp3, ogg, flac etc) and updates its tags using the `taginject` element, but it is not working.

Here are my attempts:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp3 ! decodebin ! taginject tags="title=bla,artist=blub" ! filesink location=output_file.mp3`

Result: The Pipeline runs, but it creates a 50mb file from a 4mb file, and that large file is not playable (and probably not containing tags, also).

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp3 ! taginject tags="title=test,artist=blub" ! filesink location=output_file.mp3`

Result: The pipeline runs and creates a playable output file, but it contains no tags.

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp3 ! decodebin ! taginject tags="title=test,artist=blub" ! encodebin ! filesink location=output_file.mp3`

Result: The pipeline does not run. It says taginject cannot be linked with encodebin.

I would appreciate any help on this, I just dont know what I am doing wrong (probably using the wrong elements... but I just cant find which are the right ones)

Comment: Found the (simple) solution: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp3 ! id3demux ! taginject tags="title=bla,artist=blub,album=blablub" ! id3mux ! filesink location=output_file.mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a muxer after taginject, e.g. something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp3 ! parsebin ! \
taginject tags="title=bla,artist=blub" ! id3v2mux ! \
filesink location=output_file.mp3
```

Also using parsebin avoids decoding.